# boost::any_range<gsl::string_span<>> crash in Release mode

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, cpp-core-guidelines, string-span

I'm observing a rather weird behaviour of the following piece of code:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "gsl.h"

template <typename T>
using ImmutableValueRange = boost::any_range<T, boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, /*const*/ T>;

template <typename T, typename C>
ImmutableValueRange<T> make_transforming_immutable_range(const C& container)
{
    return container | boost::adaptors::transformed([](const typename C::value_type& v) -> T 
    {
        //std::cout << "trans : " << T{ v }.data() << "\n";
        return T{ v }; 
    });
}

void f(ImmutableValueRange<gsl::cstring_span<>> r)
{
    for (const auto& c : r) {
        std::cout << c.data() << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v({ "x", "y", "z" });

    f(make_transforming_immutable_range<gsl::cstring_span<>>(v));
}
```

The idea here is to isolate the actual representation of a sequence of strings that is received as a parameter by the function `f` behind an `any_range` and `gsl::string_span` (note, the commit changing `string_view` to `string_span` has been made a couple of hours ago to GSL).

My original code did not have a `const T` as `Reference` template parameter to `any_range` (it was a simple `T`) and it crashed during execution. However, that happened only in Release mode an worked fine in Debug or RelWithDebInfo (generated by CMake). I used VS2013/2015 x64. Furthermore, trying to debug the full Release version, adding debug output to the conversion lambda eliminated the crash (my guess is it prevented some inlining). My final working solution is to specify `const T` as `Reference`.

However, I'm still wondering *why* did the crash happen in the first place? Is it the VS compiler bug? Bug in the current implementation of `string_span`? Or am I simply misusing the `boost::any_range`?

**Edit**

Just built the version with clang 3.7.0 and the behaviour is similar (works fine in debug and doesn't crash, but outputs garbage without `const T` with `-O2`). So it doesn't seem like a compiler problem.

Comment: Good luck debugging that.   Did you try debugging it? You can debug in release mode.

Comment: @WarrenP Of course. But it works perfectly fine in Debug/RelWithDebInfo modes and even with some debug output in the lambda in Release mode, kinda making debugging really hard :)

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, the `any_range`'s `dereference` method will return a reference to `T` unless the `Reference` type is specified as `const T`, thus creating a dangling reference to a temporary. This happens due to use of `any_incrementable_iterator_interface::mutable_reference_type_generator` defined in [any_iterator_interface.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/boost/range/detail/any_iterator_interface.hpp).

Therefore, the correct solution to the problem is indeed to specify `const T` as the `Reference` type in case the iterator dereferencing returns a temporary.

Comment: This was finally fixed in 1.74

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in `boost::range` and a fix was only merged in Feb of 2020, but didn't make it into `1.73`. The fix is available as of `1.74`

https://github.com/boostorg/range/pull/94

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look, I suspect the problem lies in your lambda. If I understood correctly, you end up taking a `std::string` by const reference with the following parameter declaration:

`const typename C::value_type& v`

However, you are then using `v` to construct a `cstring_span`. Here's the rub: `cstring_span` only has a constructor that goes from a non-const reference to a container type (like `std::string`). Conceptually, the constructor looks like this:

`template <class Cont>
cstring_span(Cont& c)`

So I am guessing that when you return from your lambda, a temporary is being created from `v`, and then passed to the `cstring_span` constructor in order to provide a non-const reference argument. Of course, once that temporary gets cleaned up, your `cstring_span` is left dangling.

Comment: Thank you Neil. However, in this case the `Cont` is deduced to be `std::string const` and no temporary is created (I was just stepping through the code and looked at the call stack). Furthermore, I would assume that such a dangling reference would crash the Debug version as well. I'll look deeper into it and try to figure out what the problem actually is.