# boost::any_range with optimization level -O2 causes crash

Tags: c++, boost

What is the problem with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>


using namespace boost::adaptors;


using Range =
  boost::any_range<
    int,
    boost::forward_traversal_tag,
    int,
    std::ptrdiff_t>;


void magic(const Range &) {}


int main()
{
  std::vector<int> xs{0, 1, 2};

  auto ys = xs | transformed([](auto x) { return x; });

  const Range zs = ys;
  std::vector<int> us{boost::begin(zs), boost::end(zs)};
  magic(us);

  return 0;
}
```

Complie:

```
c++ -g -std=c++14 -O2 main.cpp
```

Run and get **segfault**.

But when I compile with lower optimization level, then everything is ok.

`gdb` output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004011a5 in boost::range_detail::any_iterator<int, boost::iterators::forward_traversal_tag, int, long, boost::any_iterator_buffer<64ul> >::dereference (this=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/range/detail/any_iterator.hpp:512
512                     return m_impl->dereference();
```

Is this `boost::any_range` bug, or I misuse the library?

Program also crashes if I compile it this way:

```
c++ -g -std=c++14 -O1 -fisolate-erroneous-paths-dereference main.cpp
```

The program below crashes too, if I compile it with options `-O1 -fisolate-erroneous-paths-dereference`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>


using namespace boost::adaptors;


using Range =
  boost::any_range<
    int,
    boost::forward_traversal_tag,
    int &,
    std::ptrdiff_t>;


void magic(const Range &xs) {
  for (auto x: xs) { std::cout << xs; }
}


int main()
{
  std::vector<int> xs{0, 1, 2};
  auto ys = xs | transformed([](auto x) { return x; });
  magic(ys);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [boost bug 10493](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10493), related to [10360](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10360), which was introduced in 1.56 (2014-08) and was only finally fixed in [1.74 (2020-08)](https://github.com/boostorg/range/blame/f3ff60c3bc41e42ffebef1452deb285047a5639f/include/boost/range/detail/any_iterator_interface.hpp#L37) via [fix PR #94](https://github.com/boostorg/range/pull/94)

Until 1.74, the problem is that instead of just using your `reference` type, it wraps it in `mutable_reference_type_generator`, which prevents you from being able to return a temporary. That is, when you write:

```
using Range =
  boost::any_range<
    int,
    boost::forward_traversal_tag,
    int,
    std::ptrdiff_t>;
```

You're explicitly specifying your `reference` type to be `int`, not `int&`, because your range is basically an input range. But the boost internals are changing it to `int&` anyway, so you dangle. When you write `const int` intsead of `int`, the type trait doesn't add the reference, so you actually do end up with `const int`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually when I was typing the title for my question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535221/boostany-rangegslstring-span-crash-in-release-mode) question was offered as possible answer.

As suggested in the answer for the question, I replaced `int` with `const int` and it worked:

```
using Range =
  boost::any_range<
    int,
    boost::forward_traversal_tag,
    const int,
    std::ptrdiff_t>;
```

I decided to publish the question because the quoted question is not marked as answered.