# Type agnostic abstraction to handle forward and reverse iterators and ranges using the same runtime interface?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, range

By design forward and reverse iterators and ranges are fundamentally different types. This is nice in the compile time optimization that it allows for. Sometimes it would be nice to hide that type difference behind an abstraction that allows them to be passed to the same run-time interface.

Are there any adapters in `boost` or the `stl` that make this easy? *(ideally but not strictly C++11)*

The following code shows both the known/expected failure and the desired hypothetical:

```
    #include <boost/range.hpp>
    #include <vector>
      
    using Ints = std::vector<int>;
      
    void real(boost::iterator_range<Ints::iterator> range){}
    void fake(boost::agnostic_range<Ints::iterator> range){} // imaginary desired
      
    int main()
    {
        auto ints = Ints{1,2,3,4,5};
      
        real(boost::make_iterator_range(ints.begin(),  ints.end())); 
        real(boost::make_iterator_range(ints.rbegin(), ints.rend())); // Error
        fake(boost::make_agnsotic_range(ints.begin(),  ints.end()));  // imaginary
        fake(boost::make_agnsotic_range(ints.rbegin(), ints.rend())); // imaginary
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think so. Iterators are designed to work in template style so compiler can optimize the code well. Otherwise iterators will be very slow and useless.

Comment: There's certainly an expected trade-off. "Useless" is hyperbole and unhelpful.

Comment: imagine you need a virtual call to make `i++;` That's an over x10 slower in a loop if you cannot devirtualize the call. And then add to it several other layers of slowness for whatever reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! `Boost::any_range` type erases the iterated object type and exposes only the output type and the iterator access type.

Note that the type erasure here requires a call through a virtual function to dereference the iterator so there's a performance cost there, but as long as non-trivial operations are performed inside the loop, this cost will be likely irrelevant.

**BUG WARNING:** `boost::range` had a [big bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427395/boostany-range-with-optimization-level-o2-causes-crash) between ~`1.55`ish until release `1.74` *(2020-08)* which would cause access to destroyed items being passed through `any_range` that would cause UB (undefined behavior/probably crash) The work around to this exists in the code below where you explicitly pass the so-called reference type though the template parameters as `const` which causes some of the internal machinery to avoid tripping over the mistake.

```
    #include <boost/range/adaptor/type_erased.hpp>
    #include <boost/range/adaptor/reversed.hpp>
    #include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>
    #include <vector>
    #include <list>
    #include <iostream>

    // note const int bug workaround
    using GenericBiDirIntRange = 
        boost::any_range<int, boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, const int>; 

    void possible(GenericBiDirIntRange const &inputRange) {
        for(auto item: inputRange)
            std::cout << item << "\n";
    }
           
    // note const int bug workaround                                                           
    using type_erased_bi =
        boost::adaptors::type_erased<int, boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, const int>;
    using reversed = boost::adaptors::reversed;
                                                                                                                                    
    auto main() -> int {                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                    
        auto intVec = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4};                                                                                   
        auto intList = std::list<int>{1, 2, 3, 4};                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                    
        possible(intVec | type_erased_bi());                                                                                          
        possible(intList | reversed | type_erased_bi());                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                    
        return 0;
    }
```